# Unable to export more than 2000 records to excel from SharePoint external list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am unable to export more than 2000 records to excel from SharePoint external list. I am able to see 5000 records in external list but only 2000 records getting exported to excel.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can see 5000 items, I would assume you already set the throttling with `Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig`. So you're now good from the server side. Now the limitation comes from MS Office. You can change that by adding a new dword `Query Instances Limit` in `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\VERSION\Common\Business Data\Synchronization]` on the client machine. Set the value to 5000.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks a lot for your response. I don't think the limitation comes from MS office, because I am able to export 3358 records to excel from normal SharePoint list. So I guess the issue is with external list since unable to export more than 2000 records from external list.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted data in excel spreadsheets matters with how you setup your sharepoint list view. If you are extracting data from a listview with filtered items, it will only get the data that the listview is supposed to get.

I suggest, you extract your data from a listview that doesn't have any filters on, 'All Items'.

Hope it helps! Happy SharePointing!